# How to select a random number in a range based on date?

Tags: c#, algorithm, random

I have a list of hundreds of Sector types with ID values that range from 1..999. The user wants to see a different random Sector displayed on the web site every day.

One way to solve this is to store the randomly selected Sector's ID for the day, and use that, and then update that field with a new Sector Id the next day. But that's a bit messy, because it means I need to store an arbitrary value somewhere in the database... (or alternatively the Application state or something)

I was also thinking that I could take the list of 1..999 and use some Random algorythm to select a random number based on the date, so as long as the date is the same as the last time the random number was selected, the same number will come out.

But I'm not sure how to implement this, so I'm looking for suggestions?

Also, given the size of the range (999), and the number of available days in a year (365), would this mean that the algorythm would always miss certain Sectors because their ID doesn't map to however the Random number selection process selects the Sector ID? Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the date as seed for the `Random` class:

```
int day = (DateTime.Today - new DateTime(2000,1,1)).TotalDays;
Random rnd = new Random(day);
int id = rnd.Next(1, 1000);
```

Note that the day is calculated from a fixed start date instead of `DateTime.DayOfYear`, so it will not restart each year and only use 365 of the values.

Comment: I thought `Random` already uses the date/time as a default seed if the parameterless constructor is used.

Comment: system clock is the default seed, not datetime. Parameterless ctor will return (an int) between 0 and 2,147,483,647.

Comment: @Oded: That is correct, but in this case you want only the date part, so that the result remains the same throughout the day.

Answer (score 5):

Do you really want a random value, or do you just want to display a different Sector every day?  Random gives the possibility that the same Sector information will be displayed two (or possibly more) days in a row.  It's also quite likely that over a 365 day period, you will get several duplicates.  Using random selection from a list of 999 items, it's highly *un*likely that you'll get 365 non-duplicated numbers in 365 tries.

Is there some reason you have to start over every year?  Why not set some date (say, January 1, 2011) as your "epoch" date.  Then, to pick an item, simply subtract that date from the current date to get the number of days, divide by 999 and take the remainder, giving you the index.  That is:

```
DateTime EpochDate = new DateTime(2011, 01, 01);
TimeSpan Elapsed = DateTime.Now.Date - EpochDate;
int index = Elapsed.Days % 999;
```

At this point, `index` is a number in the range 0..998.  You can then use that number to index into your Sector IDs.  Either index directly (so Jan 1 2011 will get the first sector ID, Jan 2 will get the second, etc.), or do some kind of calculation on the index to "randomize" it.

Comment: Should it not be TotalDays?

Comment: @XzaR where do you get TotalDays?

Comment: Last line on Elapsed.Days should be Elapsed.TotalDays? Days is only current year of that date count which is 366 with leap year if I am correct. Then it will not be possible to get all 999 indices while total is count days since epoch. Maybe I am thinking wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Answering your second question on combinatorics:

You have 999 numbers and 365 days.
You can select one random number each day, which means in no case can you show more than 365 (distinct) numbers. Ofcoure some numbers might repeat as well. You have to devise logic based on how you want to represent.

It is indeed desirable that your random object must persist for 365 days in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) class and expire the content at midnight. When the cache entry doesn't exist, create a new one with a random value, expiring at midnight...

For the random value, use [`System.Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) - no need to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: As long as the application doesn't recycle during that period!

Comment: @David - quite right, which is why I suggest recreating the entry when it doesn't exist. Agreed, it will not persist throughout the day if the app recycles, but this might be enough to solve the problem for the OP.